# Difference in days between two different date formats

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Just wondering how can I change different formats of dates and then calculate the number of days between the two.

I have one date in the format

```
 2016-04-01 00:06:13:313
```

And another in the format

```
 06/05/2016  00:00:00
```

Just want to find out how many days are between the two dates.

Many thanks

Comment: If they are both in date formats, you can accomplish that easily. Because on Excel , the cell on a date format is just a number in general format, so you can work with them. And what is the :313 unit?

Comment: The unit 313 is going into milliseconds, I tried to use Datedif, which works if the dates are in the same format. But as there are not I cant

Comment: I'm not sure how to change the first format into the second, normal ctrl-1 formatting doesnt work

Comment: How did you use DATEIF? And have you tried DAYS() Function?

Comment: DATEDIF(1st date, 2second date, "d")

Comment: The date format doesn't matter, like the first format gives 42461,0043171296 in number format and the second 42130 in number format. In the Days function you have to input the final date and the initial and you receive the number in days, you just have to format the formula in General Format or number format

Comment: I had to format the date format as custom: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss,000. However, couldn't make the miliseconds separator as : and used , instead. And 42130 is a year out, i read it wrong sorry =]. I am using Excel 2016

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to re-format the data and the displayed values do not change, then the values are probably *Text* rather than numbers formatted as dates.

If this is the case, with the values in **A1** and **A2**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,13,8))+RIGHT(A1,3)/(86400000)
```

and in **B2** enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A2,13,8))
```

Then format the **B** cells:

[image]

In another cell, enter:

```
=B2-B1
```

[image]